# How can I cancel a blocking call such as select() or read()?

Tags: multithreading, select, blocking, interrupt

As the title says, how can I cancel a blocking call such as select() or (in the case of serial comm and similar) read() from another thread? What is the traditional way of solving things like this? I suppose one could use a small timeout and that would probably work fine but that seems like a bit of a hack to me.

Comment: There is no cancellation.  There is only a timeout and a decision whether or not to retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way of interrupting `select(2)` is the [**`self-pipe trick`**](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html). The input/output calls are better served by having the descriptors *non-blocking* and handling `EAGAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations you should probably use a small or immediate timeout and have additional logic that handles when/how/why the next select/read attempt is made.