# How to interrupt a blocking accept() call

Tags: unix, signals

I have written a multithreaded application in C. I have two threads created, one for catching all the signals and another for `accept()`-ing client connections. When I kill the appilcation using `killproc`, the thread with the `accept` call is not interrupted. How can I fix that?

The code looks like:

```
int stop_exec=0;

sigCatcherThread()
{
    int sig
    sigset_t allsignals;
    sigfillset(allsignals);

    do{
          sigwait(&allsignals, &sig);
          if(sig==SIGTERM)
            stop_exec=1;
    }while(!stop_exec)

}

clientHandler()
{
  ...
  while(!stop_exec)
  {
      accept(...);
  }

main()
{
   pthread_create(..., sigCatcherThread,..);
   pthread_create(..., clientHandler,...);
}
```

Comment: Use the **self-pipe trick**, see [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016977/how-can-i-cancel-a-blocking-call-such-as-select-or-read

Comment: There's nothing to fix. If there's some reason you *need* that thread to get the signal, explain what that is and we'll tell you how to fix *that*.

Answer (score 0):

Here you see the use of interrupted system calls. But the convenience of a signal handling thread is probably higher than the use of interrupted systems calls.

So you need you client handler to block until it can accept an incoming connection or the signal occurs.  Waiting for potential input means either signal driven IO -- a path I wouldn't follow -- or select(2) (or pool).  But select(2) can wait only on IO. So transform your signal occurrence in IO: open a pipe, have your signal handling thread write to the pipe when SIGQUIT occurs and have your client thread select(2) for the socket and the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread receives a signal targeted to a process. So, it must be not the thread blocked on `accept()`. See [signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) for more details.

As already mentioned here, you should probably be using an event loop based on `select()`. I would suggest using [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to interrupt the blocking `accept` call. Just make sure that if the thread does return from `accept`, say by receiving an actual connection, it won't do anything harmful.

If there's some specific reason you need the `accept` call to interrupt, explain what it is. Likely there's a simple way to remove the requirement.